# Multiple Lambda functions are being triggered for single batch size

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have added a trigger to Lambda to Pool for messages from SQS (Standard) with batch size of 10000 and batch window of 10 seconds.
For testing, I added 3 messages to my SQS so ideally there should be one lambda function to process all 3 messages but this is not the case, it's triggering 3 lambda functions each for one message. Can anyone help me is there something which I'm missing here?

[image: Lambda SQS Trigger]

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone help me is there something which I'm missing here?

Yes. Because there are always at least **five pooling threads** for each lambda function. Each pooler will invoke a function. So its possibile that your 3 messages were pooled by three different poolers, which then invoked your function 3 times (each time with one message). From [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-adds-amazon-simple-queue-service-to-supported-event-sources/):

> the Lambda service will begin polling the SQS queue using **five parallel long-polling connections**.

Comment: is there some setting using which I can restrict the number of threads i.e. I want that only one lambda function process the complete batch?

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb No, you can't restrict that.